# css class synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Could you add [cssclass](/questions/tagged/cssclass) as a synonym of [css-classes](/questions/tagged/css-classes)?

While you are at it add [animations](/questions/tagged/animations) as a synonym of [animation](/questions/tagged/animation).

Comment: I'm deciding between retagging all 19 existing [cssclass] posts to [css-classes], and destroying both equally low-question-count tags. What's with that "Sorry, this is a duplicate question of" in your post anyway?

Comment: @bolt try asking a new question with the same wording but different tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time I saw this, the [animations](/questions/tagged/animations) --> [animation](/questions/tagged/animation) synonym had already gone through.

I retagged all [cssclass](/questions/tagged/cssclass) to [css-classes](/questions/tagged/css-classes): I don't believe the former should exist. It's only there, I think, because of a `CssClass` property in .NET. Out of the 19 questions I retagged, maybe 3 or 4 of them dealt with this -- using the new tag suffices to get the point across (and "CssClass" can be found through a text search).